# c++: How to obtain context when callback doesn't provide user arg?

Tags: c++, callback, scope

First, some background:
(Note: Though I'm in non-.NET Win32 land, this is really a C++ question)

I'm using a 3rd party API which requires you to register a callback function in order to know when an async operation is complete. Gotta use the callback, no way around it.

A non-OOP implementation would be something like this:

```
void __stdcall MyCbFcn(int value)
{
   do something with 'value'...
}

API_RegisterCallback(MyCbFcn);
```

Pretty standard stuff.

BUT...
My code is OOP, with multiple instances rx'ing the callback, thus the callback needs to be routed to the object that registered it.

Knowing that folks do this, callbacks typically include a user var, something like:

```
void __stdcall MyCbFcn(int value, U32 user)
{
   do something with 'value'...
}

API_RegisterCallback(MyCbFcn, someUserValue);
```

and more specifically, when combined with OOP, this user arg allows you to get back into context:
(written inline for brevity):

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass()
   {
      API_RegisterCallback(MyClass::StaticCbFcn, (U32)this);
   }

private:
   static void __stdcall StaticCbFcn(int value, U32 user)
   {
      MyClass* pThis = (MyClass*)user;
      pThis->InstanceCbFcn(value);
   }
   void InstanceCbFcn(int value)
   {
      ... do some work in context ...
   }
}
```

BUT, my API doesn't feature a user arg :(

So now my question:
How I can get back into context?

I've considered kinda sketchy things like defining a "pool" of 100 distinct callbacks and assigning them as objects are created, but that seems like a real hack.

An obvious solution ... if I were in e.g. JavaScript :) ... would be to use an anonymous function, but AFAIK C++ doesn't have anything like that.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The callback doesn't receive any pointer at all?  For example, in Win32 there's a callback which receives a user-allocated `OVERLAPPED*`... and while that structure is defined for use by the Win32 API, you can stick data of your choice right before or right after it in memory and then easily find it in the callback.

Comment: Details on this are found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/17/10106259.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/20/10107027.aspx

Comment: Correct, the callback doesn't receive any pointer at all. A pretty stunning omission, huh? The whole API (vendor-provided, for controlling a h/w device via USB) is a mess, and this is par for the course. But it's the only thing for which I couldn't devise a palatable solution.

Comment: Developers of API's that don't allow an 'aux' pointer around callbacks should be forced to spend 20 years writing PHP while listening to a loop of Ed Miliband speeches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"100 distinct callbacks" is really the only thing you can do, thus you use the function address as identifying parameter. It might help to implement the different functions as template with a constant parameter:

```
template < unsinged N >
void StaticCbFcn( int value )
{
    map[ N ].InstanceCbFcn( value );
}
```

Comment: You need some more (and more complicated) template code to initialize a table of function pointers, but yes that will work.

Comment: This is the only working solution I think, but you of course have an arbitrary limitation.

Comment: In reality I'd never need more than, say, 3 distinct callbacks. So I'd make 10 just for good measure. So I can live with the arbitrary limit.

Comment: Can someone please explain how this works in more detail? I am dealing with a very similar API and can't seem to figure out any way around just using global variables to get additional data into the callback.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 It uses C++ Templates to generate a Function based on an compile time constant. When taking the address of that function (StaticCbFcn<4>), the compiler have to provide different function addresses for different constants (N). Inside the function, the constant N can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with boost bind:

```
boost::bind(&my::function_to_call_cb, this, _1, context));

void my_impl::function_to_call_cb(int result, std::string context)
```

Comment: boost::bind() and std::bind() return a function object which can't be passed to an API that takes a function pointer. I believe that's what the original question is about.