# How do I pass a member function as a parameter callback function with regards to Bluetooth on Windows?

Tags: c++, bluetooth

I'm trying to get a heart rate from a heart rate monitor using Windows' Bluetooth API, but I've encountered a problem with the [BluetoothGATTRegisterEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450804(v=vs.85).aspx) function, namely the fourth parameter which expects a PFNBLUETOOTH_GATT_EVENT_CALLBACK callback function as a parameter. Doing the following code works fine:

```
// Function definition
void SomeEvent(BTH_LE_GATT_EVENT_TYPE EventType, PVOID EventOutParameter, PVOID Context)
{ /* Function code */}

// Calling BluetoothGATTRegisterEvent
hr = BluetoothGATTRegisterEvent(
                hLEDevice,
                EventType,
                &EventParameterIn,
                SomeEvent,
                NULL,
                &EventHandle,
                BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);
```

However, if I attempt to pass a member function (e.g. HeartRateMonitor::SomeEvent instead of just SomeEvent) I get the following error:

```
argument of type "void (HeartRateMonitor::*)(BTH_LE_GATT_EVENT_TYPE EventType, PVOID EventOutParameter, PVOID Context)" is incompatible with parameter of type "PFNBLUETOOTH_GATT_EVENT_CALLBACK"
```

My first instinct was to try to use a function pointer or std::bind object, but neither of these worked either. Are there some special considerations that need to be made when passing a callback function as this parameter, or am I missing something obvious regarding member functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++: How to obtain context when callback doesn't provide user arg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583205/c-how-to-obtain-context-when-callback-doesnt-provide-user-arg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the [`BluetoothGATTRegisterEvent`'s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bluetoothleapis/nf-bluetoothleapis-bluetoothgattregisterevent) `CallbackContext` parameter is for.

Have to pass a `static` member function as a callback and `this` as a `CallbackContext`. Non-static member functions have an implicit `this` as first parameter ([`__thiscall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=vs-2017)) and cannot be used as callback.

In the callback you can cast the `Context` to `this` and access the other members of your class.

Example:

```
class HeartRateMonitor {
public:
    //...
    void MemberFun(BTH_LE_GATT_EVENT_TYPE EventType, PVOID EventOutParameter, PVOID Context)
    {}

    static void StaticMemberFun(BTH_LE_GATT_EVENT_TYPE EventType, PVOID EventOutParameter, PVOID Context)
    {
        HeartRateMonitor* pThis = static_cast<HeartRateMonitor*>(Context);

        /* Function code */
        // and here you could access your class non-static data by pThis->...
        // or call a non-static method, so you don't need to always writhe `pThis`
    }

    HeartRateMonitor()
    {
        HANDLE hLEDevice = 0;
        BTH_LE_GATT_EVENT_TYPE EventType = CharacteristicValueChangedEvent;
        PVOID EventParameterIn = 0;
        BLUETOOTH_GATT_EVENT_HANDLE EventHandle = 0;
        HRESULT hr = 0;

        hr = ::BluetoothGATTRegisterEvent(  // ok
                hLEDevice,
                EventType,
                &EventParameterIn,
                &HeartRateMonitor::StaticMemberFun,
                this,
                &EventHandle,
                BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);

        hr = ::BluetoothGATTRegisterEvent(  // error C2664: 'unsigned long BluetoothGATTRegisterEvent(HANDLE,BTH_LE_GATT_EVENT_TYPE,void *,PFNBLUETOOTH_GATT_EVENT_CALLBACK,void *,BLUETOOTH_GATT_EVENT_HANDLE *,unsigned long)': cannot convert argument 4 from 'void (__cdecl HeartRateMonitor::* )(BTH_LE_GATT_EVENT_TYPE,void *,void *)' to 'PFNBLUETOOTH_GATT_EVENT_CALLBACK'
                hLEDevice,
                EventType,
                &EventParameterIn,
                &HeartRateMonitor::MemberFun,
                this,
                &EventHandle,
                BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);
    }
};
```

<kbd>[Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d-MSNy)</kbd>

Comment: I had same problem however I could't solve this with your suggestion , could you give specific example @Mihayl about this because no meter what I can try I am facing same error which mentions about his  in the questions

Answer (score 1):

Put "CALLBACK" before a function name:

```
// Function definition
void CALLBACK SomeEvent(BTH_LE_GATT_EVENT_TYPE EventType, PVOID EventOutParameter, PVOID Context)
{ /* Function code */}
```

It works for me (VC 2019 and mingw).